# Trying to forward domain to a different port

Tags: spring-boot, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running a Springboot application on Windows Server 2012 R2. It seems to demand port 80 when executed from a fat JAR but I don't even want to consider freeing up that port on a Windows server. There seem to be far too many steps involved and I've failed miserably before. In order to bypass this problem, at least temporarily, I was wondering if it was possible to forward anyone that hits my url, i.e. http://webapp (default port 80) to http://ipAddress:8081 and continue to mask the IP/port address with the pretty url. Is this possible and how would I do this?

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=10.99.128.6 connectport=8081 connectaddress=10.99.128.6
```

Apparently this command wasn't enough. When I hit `10.99.128.6:80` it stays at port 80...

Even after examining and confirming the active port mappings:

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```

Am I missing the point? I'm have no server admin experience. Just need to get this one thing going.

In effect, `http://webapp` or `http://10.99.128.6:80` should run `http://10.99.128.6:81`.

Comment: you use plesk or  IIS ?

Comment: Neither. Springboot will launch the entire web application server after executing a single JAR. I removed IIS to free up port 80 but there are other restrictions I can't figure out. I'm thinking that if I host on port 8081 and any time somebody hits port 80 (default domain port) then redirecting them to port 8081 (where the app actually works) would be ideal...

Comment: Did you have a look at [3.2 Change the HTTP port](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port)?

Comment: Thank you, but again that's not the issue... I need port forwarding on the server side.

Comment: in my case with spring mvc application i used **Filtres ISAPI** to do the forword, but you will need **IIS** in this case